# ReactJS get image from the element above

Tags: reactjs

I need the element {"../images/type/" + eq.image_eq} when I trigger my onClick. In jQuery I would just simply refer to the DOM element before but how to achieve that in React?

```
renderEqui() {
  return _.map(this.state.equi, eq => {
    return (
      <>
        <img src={"../images/type/" + eq.image_eq} />
        <img src="../images/misc/equiped.png" onClick={this.changeImage} />
      </>
    );
  });
}
```

I already tried with parameters but no success. I need to retrieve this image in order to modify another component's image.

Comment: Do you need the `<img />` DOM element, or the value of `eq`?

Comment: Only the value of my src in fact, not the DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 renderEqui() {
    return _.map(this.state.equi, eq => {
        const imageSrc = "../images/type/" + eq.image_eq;
        return (
                            <img src={imageSrc}/>
                            <img src="../images/misc/equiped.png" onClick={()=>this.changeImage(imageSrc )}/>
        );
    });
```

Your changeImage function will be like this:

```
changeImage = (imageSrc) => {
  cconsole.log(imageSrc)
 }
```

Comment: I missed how to write the onClick then... It's working thanks you!